# How to return data from ajax to select tag

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two select tag in auth.register.

```
<div class = "form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <label for="years">Name of Course*</label>     
    <select class="form-control input-sm required" id="courses_name" name="alumni_course">
        <option value="">-- Select Any one --</option>
        @foreach($coursename as $coursenames)
            <option value="{{ $coursenames->id.','.$coursenames->coursename }}" >{{ $coursenames->coursename }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class = "form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="dvPassport" style="display:none">
    <label for="years">Name of Branch*</label>     

    <select class="form-control input-sm required" id="branch_name" name="alumni_branch">
        @if(isset($branchname))
            @foreach($branchname as $branchnames)
                <option value="{{ $branchnames->id }}" >{{ $branchnames->branchname }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
</div>
```

If from Name of Course option, any one select B.E./B.TECH. or DIPLOMA, then Name of Branch will be show and data will be related B.E./B.TECH. or DIPLOMA.

MY ajax in same page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#courses_name").change(function() {

            var courses_name1 = $("#courses_name").val();
            var courses_name2 = courses_name1.split(",");
            var id = courses_name2[0];
            var courses_name2 = courses_name2[1];
            if (courses_name2 == 'B.E./B.TECH.' || courses_name2 == 'DIPLOMA') {
                $("#dvPassport").show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "findbranch",
                    data: {
                        'id': id
                    },
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $("#branch_name").html(data.html);
                    //console.log(data);
                });
            } else {
                $("#dvPassport").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Route is:**

```
Route::get('findbranch','Auth\RegisterController@findbranch');
```

Controller is:

```
public function findbranch(Request $request)
{
    $branchname = branchname::where('course_id', $request->id)->get();
    $html = view('auth.register')->with(compact('branchname'))->render();
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html]);
}
```

But data is not showing in Name of Branch.

Comment: In ajax url change it to '{{url("findbranch")}}' and see network tab, does it execute the request?

Comment: paste the `auth.register` contents please. update it in question.

Comment: auth.register is above select tag and ajax

Comment: Is the ajax executed? Check your network tab and see what it returns.

Comment: GET http://localhost/millennium_alumni_laravel/findbranch?id=7 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: what error you see under `response` tab

Comment: status: 500,   Type: xhr,   initiator: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:1,

Comment: I delete one line from controller. NOw this is:  $branchname = branchname::where('course_id', $request->id)->get();
       //$html = view('auth.register')->with(compact('branchname'))->render();
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $branchname]);

Comment: It is giving object in console. But not showing in select

Comment: Can you post what is being outputted to the console? @user3526766

Comment: {success: true, html: Array(1)}
html: Array(1)
0:
branchname: "dsdgd"
course_id: 7
created_at: "2018-11-17 11:44:25"
id: 4
updated_at: "2018-11-17 11:44:25"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
success: true
__proto__: Object

Comment: See the answer i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$html = view('auth.register')->with(compact('branchname'))->render();
```

This will solve your problem.

**Edit :**

Problem is with your `$("#branch_name").html(data.html);`

it should be `$("#branch_name").html(data);`

Comment: GET http://localhost/millennium_alumni_laravel/findbranch?id=7 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If I run localhost/millennium_alumni_laravel/findbranch?id=7 direct then error:   (2/2) ErrorException
Undefined variable: collegename (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\millennium_alumni_laravel\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Comment: So, it means there is a variable you are using inside view named `collegename` which is not passed to it.

Comment: Hold on i don't see any `collegename` in code you posted in question.
Do `php artisan view:clear` to clean you cached view

Comment: Check if your view have the variable mentioned in error.

Comment: I see you are also not passing the course name to view

Comment: Yes there is $collegename. But it not a part of both of them. It is just only showing some data when register.blade.php is load. It is not related to AJAX.

Comment: In Ajax findBranch why are you passing auth.register as view then.

Comment: So. how to do that. Any other option?

Comment: I have to click on Name of Course and related data should be show by AJAX in other select tag Name of Branch

Comment: The view you are passing should have only branch select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184141/discussion-between-user3526766-and-omar-abdullah).

Comment: Thankyou. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

$.ajax({

```
        url: base_url + '/findbranch',
        type: "GET",
        data: {'id': id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

           $("#branch_name").html(data.html);
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

Test adding:

```
use App\branchname;
```

at top of your controller.

Comment: I delete one line from controller. NOw this is: $branchname = branchname::where('course_id', $request->id)->get(); //$html = view('auth.register')->with(compact('branchname'))->render(); return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $branchname]);

Comment: It is giving object in console. But not showing in select